# mysql query result different in console than in export file

Tags: mysql

I am writing a query to crate a list of folders and wildcards from a database table which will then be used in a batch file to copy a large number of folders. I have written a query which returns what I'm interested in, however I noticed that the query result is different when exporting to a file or displaying to the console than it is in the mysql client itself. Specifically, I am escaping the "\" character by doubling it up, but when writing to a file the escape character shows.

An example of the query I used is as follows:

```
SELECT CONCAT('\\',SUBSTR("Foo",1,1),'\\',"Foo",'\\*.*') AS 'List';
```

From the mysql command line the query returns the result I'd expect:

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('\\',SUBSTR("Foo",1,1),'\\',"Foo",'\\*.*') AS 'List';
+------------+
| List       |
+------------+
| \F\Foo\*.* |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However if I write the same query to a file named test.sql and try to pipe in the query and display or pipe out the output I'm getting the escape character in the output:

```
C:\testing123>echo SELECT CONCAT('\\',SUBSTR("Foo",1,1),'\\', "Foo",'\\*.*') AS 'List'; > test.sql

C:\testing123>mysql < test.sql

List
\\F\\Foo\\*.*
```

I get the same result when I use INTO OUTFILE

I've tried removing the escape character from the test.sql query file but that just causes the query to throw an error (as would be expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe different output methods use a different sql_mode concerning character escaping.
When you disable character escaping with command `set sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';`, then above query will give you two backslashes also in the console (or will suppress errors if you only write one backslash in the query):

```sql
set sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';
SELECT CONCAT('\',SUBSTR("Foo",1,1),'\',"Foo",'\*.*') AS 'List';
-> \F\Foo\*.*

set sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';
SELECT CONCAT('\\',SUBSTR("Foo",1,1),'\\',"Foo",'\\*.*') AS 'List';
-> \\F\\Foo\\*.*

set sql_mode = '';
SELECT CONCAT('\\',SUBSTR("Foo",1,1),'\\',"Foo",'\\*.*') AS 'List';
-> \F\Foo\*.*

set sql_mode = '';
SELECT CONCAT('\',SUBSTR("Foo",1,1),'\',"Foo",'\*.*') AS 'List';
-> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\',"Foo",'\*.*') AS 'List'' at line 1
```

Comment: Thank you Stephan, I was able to use SET sql_mode='NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES' and INTO OUTFILE in order to achieve my goal.